# How to redirect a user to different dashboards based on a level field in the '''users''' table in Laravel Breeze?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-breeze

Please forgive me if my question is too generic but I am at my wits end.

I have a users table with a level field as shown given below:

`$table->unsignedSmallInteger('level')->after('password');`

I want to redirect the user to different dashboards based on the value of the level field. For example for level 0 user

`\admin\dashboard`

for level 1 user

`\user\dashboard`

I am using Laravel 8.4 and laravel/breeze for authentication.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution.

1. On `routes\web.php` I have commented out the default dashboard route and created a new route for `/dashboard` and pointed it to `App\Http\Controllers\DashboardsController@index`

```
// Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
//     return view('dashboard');
// })->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';

Route::get('/dashboard','App\Http\Controllers\DashboardsController@index')->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');
```

2. `index` function of `DashboardsController`

```
public function index() {
        $data['authenticated_user'] = Auth::user();
        if($data['authenticated_user']->level == 0) {
            echo "Admin";
        } elseif($data['authenticated_user']->level == 1) {
            echo "Employee";
        } else {
            echo "Security";
        }
    }
```

Basically this will accomplish what I want to achieve.

Thanks